# Flutter android/IOS didn't detect screenshot screenshot_callback

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Its didn't got any screenshot event and not have any logs or print please help!
I add the uses permission like this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE" />`
maybe can someone send solution?

```
ScreenshotCallback screenshotCallback = ScreenshotCallback();
// Add this to initState method
screenshotCallback.addListener(() {
  //Void funtions are implemented
  print('detect screenshot');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check that you have added the android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE permission to your app's manifest file.
- Check that you are calling the addListener() method on the ScreenshotCallback object in the initState() method of your app's main activity.
- Check that you are printing the log message in the onScreenshotCaptured() method of the ScreenshotCallback object.

Try this code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
  if (ScreenshotManager.isScreenshotDetectionSupported()) {
    // Screenshot detection is supported.
  } else {
    // Screenshot detection is not supported.
  }
}
```